# Retrieve Checkbox Value that has been stored on DB

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I've been stored my checkbox value into DB using this code

```
$request->merge([ 
    'revisi_dokumen' => implode(',', (array) $request->get('revisi_dokumen'))
    ]);
```

But now i can't get it back when i try to edit(in editpage.blade), i want the checkbox is checked if it's value same as value in DB, how do do that guys ? please kindly help me solve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You used `implode()` to store, use `explode()` to retrieve.

```
$values = explode(",", $model->revisi_dokumen);
```

In your view you check if the checkbox value is in the array

```
<input type="checkbox" name="revisi_dokumen[]" value="1" {{ in_array('1', $values) ? 'checked' : '' }}>One
```

Comment: its work buddy :) thanks you for helping, may God bless you :)